# SVG confuses 'fill' with 'stroke-color'

Tags: css, svg

I have a closed `<path>` drawn in the shape of a star. The problem is simple but frustrating: when I try to fill its insides through attributes or CSS, the only thing that changes is the stroke color. I've stared rather hard at the path details but see nothing special about it. Even the most basic tutorials show how to fill closed paths, so it must be possible.

[Here's a JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/badido/3) I request a blue fill but get a blue stroke. Note I try both templates from `<defs>` and a non-template equivalent.

Comment: what's closing the first `</g>`?

Comment: Sorry, editing goof: pulled out a lot of irrelevant content. Fixed and changed JSBin link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is working correctly.  It is just that the star itself is limited to that band.  (there is not middle section in your star for the svg to fill)

change the d attribute to this:

m 15.64,213.212 117.92,105.865 -33.174,154.959 c -1.035,4.834 0.876,9.824 4.876,12.729 3.999,2.906 9.335,3.181 13.613,0.704 l 137.124,-79.434 137.124,79.434 c 1.944,1.126 4.107,1.684 6.265,1.684 2.588,0 5.167,-0.802 7.348,-2.387 4,-2.906 5.911,-7.896 4.876,-12.729 L 378.44,319.077 496.359,213.212 c 3.679,-3.302 5.065,-8.462 3.538,-13.164 -1.528,-4.702 -5.683,-8.061 -10.6,-8.571 L 331.671,175.143 267.425,30.279 c -2.004,-4.519 -6.483,-7.432 -11.427,-7.432 -4.944,0 -9.423,2.914 -11.427,7.433 L 180.329,175.143 22.702,191.477 c -4.917,0.51 -9.072,3.869 -10.6,8.571 -1.528,4.702 -0.141,9.862 3.538,13.164 z

and you should see what I mean

Comment: I'm very grateful for the correction, and forgive me for the lack of understanding, but what does your path do that the previous doesn't? Paths, as I understand them, are lines, not definitions of whitespace.

Comment: so what you have is an outer path and an inner path in your original.  The inner path has limited the shape from occupying the middle section.  All I did was to take a vector drawing program (inkscape) and remove the inner path to allow the inner section to be filled. What you might be missing is that the 'pen' that draws the path can lift up and be placed back down again in another location to start drawing again.  The path is not just a line, but the resulting object that the collection of lines describe.  I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Perhaps a simpler explanation is that what you thought was a "stroke" was  actually not a stroke.  What you had was a blue star shape with a slightly smaller star-shaped hole in it.